# Drupal Views integration

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

This relates to Drupal 6 and Views 2.

I'm not new to Drupal, but I am new to problematically using Views.

I have a custom view defined in a module which is integrated with data like this (I think):

```
$view->base_table = 'tblName';
```

I am integrating a third-party API.  It returns me a pretty vanilla PHP object.

I need a way for list returns from that API to become the base_table for the view, on the fly.  Is this possible?  The ugly solution I was think of was making every return item a node, and then using those as the "base_table".  I think that would work, but it seems ugly.  I don't want a bunch of nodes hanging around for later.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, but I ended up creating a routine based around Drupal's caching mechanism.  I'm droping and creating a table on the fly and handing that table to Views.  The table is populated every five minutes by the API.  It can be forcibly re-populated by clearing the Drupal cache.

I tried using MySQL Temporary tables, but they didn't persist well enough.  I wonder if there is a way to make them more connection-persistent, or to last a certain amount of time.